# Modernizr - PHP conditional statement based on HTML class?

Tags: php, modernizr

I am using modernizr on my site to detect whether the device is a touch device or not. Within my PHP I would like to use a conditional statement to display specific information that changes depending on if the device used to access the site is touch capable or not.

Modernizr adds the class `no-touchevents` to my `<html>` tag if the device does not support touch. How can I write a PHP conditional to display different content for this class? I know in jQuery I can use `if ($(ele).hasClass('no-touchevents')) { }` but I'm not sure how to accomplish this with PHP

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: @JayBlanchard This is not a duplicate. Not only that, but the question you marked as duplicate does not even have an accepted answer. I already know how to do feature detection using Modernizr, my question is how to create a conditional statement in PHP based on that feature detection.

Comment: Do you know that php is server side and is parsed before the page is served to the browser and js is client side and parsed after the page is sent to the browser. So. Unless you reload the page or you use Ajax you can’t do what you’re looking for

Comment: Did you read the part in the answer which says that PHP is not really setup for this? Not only that, but you failed to show how you tried to do this with PHP. You would have to send information to PHP from the JavaScript in order for PHP to act on it. Perhaps AJAX? Perhaps redirection? Since there is no clear cut path this also makes your question far too broad.

Comment: It says "PHP is the wrong way to do detection." I'm not doing detection with PHP, I'm doing it with Javascript.

Comment: Then you have a couple of suggestions here for how to move forward then.